# Epson Artisan 800 on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: ubuntu, networking, printer, network-printer, cross-platform

**Update for Ubuntu 10.04**: Printing should work 'out-of-box', scanning still needs the newer sane backend.

Looking for a known good way to setup an Epson Artisan 800 on Ubuntu specifically or any linux box in general. It is a printer/scanner with ethernet/wifi/usb. I'd like to use it as a network printer/scanner being able to do both from my Windows and Ubuntu machines; however, if it needs to be physically connected to a computer (preferably the Ubuntu machine) that is doable (again, then sharing print/scan functions to the network).

Basically, I'm looking for someone who has used this printer/scanner (or similar) in a multi-platform environment to share how the set it up and how well it worked.

**Updated:** A little more information, like most printers (I expect) the documentation for the printer basically says, "don't use plug-n-play, run our setup CD from your Windows/Mac system", to do *anything* (set it up for network use even). I guess that's to make it easy for anyone else to setup, but when you're looking to use it with an unsupported (by Epson's documentation) OS, you're just stuck on your own. What I was hoping for was someone who could say,

> "Forget the bundled software, do [this] to set it up on wifi manually, install [this] to connect to the scanner from [os], printing works with [this] driver - at least that's how I set it up."

I'll will (and have so far) use the information here, and post my own setup when I'm done, if there's no one else out there with that experience.

Comment: And just to vent, when will printer manufactures stop using their driver installations to install junk software all over the place? Give me a break Epson, and just install the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all there:

[openprinting.org : Epson Artisan 800 page](http://openprinting.org/show_printer.cgi?recnum=Epson-Artisan_800)

Basically it just should work.

Comment: Yeah, I know there's drivers for the printing side of things, but what about over the network/wifi, scanning etc?

Comment: sane with the epson2 backend apparently supports scanning with Epson artisan 700/800. Recent Sane releases are network transparent, and CUPS should be, too.

Comment: Needed to install the Jaunty gutenprint package (I'm running Ibex currently), then it worked out of box. Ibex version of gutenprint just spooled paper.

Answer (score 1):

Just installed the sane-backends version 1.0.21.  Using this link:  http://mp610.blogspot.com/2008/04/give-your-scanner-new-freshly-sane.html.  I used xsane image scanning program and was able to sacan in color and and black and white.

Comment: The development release backends were exactly what was needed to get scanning working.

Answer (score 1):

Artisan 725 installed by default (networked) in Ubuntu 11:10

Works fine scanning up to and including 600dpi

fails, with 'communincation error" if over 600 dpi